# How does the individual variance of a match of a game affect long term stat confidence?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, confidence-interval, variance

I play a [1v1 game mode where opponents shoot a giant football at each others goal](https://youtu.be/6qC5rwZZjkA?t=5m13s).

I wish to increase my shots defended decimal.

```
// EXAMPLE END MATCH RESULT
ME: 4 SHOTS - 4 GOALS
OPPONENT: 12 SHOTS - 2 GOALS

Shots defended = (OPPONENTS SHOTS - OPPONENTS GOALS) / OPPONENTS SHOTS
Shots defended = (12 SHOTS - 2 GOALS) / 12 SHOTS
Shots defended = 10 / 12 
Shots defenced = 0.8333
```

This variable has a huge amount of variance between games, being anywhere from 0% - 100%.

What steps must be taken to work out how many games I need to sample to have a 90% confidence on the shots defended stat?

Answer (score 0):

In my search for an answer, I have came [across this tool.](http://epitools.ausvet.com.au/content.php?page=1Proportion&Proportion=0.65&Precision=0.05&Conf=0.9&Population=)

It states:

```
Sample size is calculated using the formula:

n = (Z2 � P(1 � P))/e2

where:
Z = value from standard normal distribution corresponding to desired confidence level (Z=1.96 for 95% CI)
P is expected true proportion
e is desired precision (half desired CI width).
```

So assuming expect my true portion of shots defended to be 0.65 and I am happy with a desired precision of + or - 0.05 and want a 90% confidence level then I need a total population (opponents shots in this case) to be 247.